# how to modify Iperf TCP connection timeout?

Tags: tcp, mininet, iperf, iperf3

I am using mininet for emulation of a network. My network has a delay of 3000ms(linear topology of 3 switches).When I tried to do iperf I got Connection failed : No route to host error in client. After a lot of time with the help of internet i came to know that this is happening because of large delay of network which causes ACK packet delayed. Thus thia ACK pcket for SYN will client after timeout. So I want to modify this timeout value. How can I do this. I am using iperf2 and ubuntu18.04. ( I think using iperf3 this is possible with --connect-timeout nms)

Answer (score 2):

iperf 2 doesn't support --connect-timeouts. The preferred way to control that is via the operating system itself, e.g. syn retries.  [More on that here.](https://www.justsomestuff.co.uk/wiki/doku.php/linux/syn_tcp_timeout) We don't think we should be messing with TCP fundamentals directly as we want to separate testing from the things under test.

As an aside, iperf 2.0.14 has a --connect-only option which can be used to measure the TCP 3WHS performance.  We also added a --connect-retries for application level retries.

Bob